# interface, quero que ela salve o nome e o telefone em uma lista txt

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

class Application:
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.fontePadrao = ("Arial", "10")
        self.primeiroContainer = Frame(master)
        self.primeiroContainer["pady"] = 10
        self.primeiroContainer.pack()

        self.segundoContainer = Frame(master)
        self.segundoContainer["padx"] = 20
        self.segundoContainer.pack()

        self.terceiroContainer = Frame(master)
        self.terceiroContainer["padx"] = 20
        self.terceiroContainer.pack()

        self.quartoContainer = Frame(master)
        self.quartoContainer["pady"] = 20
        self.quartoContainer.pack()

        self.titulo = Label(self.primeiroContainer, text="Lista Telefonica")
        self.titulo["font"] = ("Arial", "10", "bold")
        self.titulo.pack()

        self.nomeLabel = Label(self.segundoContainer,text="Nome", font=self.fontePadrao)
        self.nomeLabel.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.nome = Entry(self.segundoContainer)
        self.nome["width"] = 30
        self.nome["font"] = self.fontePadrao
        self.nome.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.telefoneLabel = Label(self.terceiroContainer, text="Telefone:", font=self.fontePadrao)
        self.telefoneLabel.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.senha = Entry(self.terceiroContainer)
        self.senha["width"] = 30
        self.senha["font"] = self.fontePadrao
        self.senha["show"] = ""
        self.senha.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.autenticar = Button(self.quartoContainer)
        self.autenticar["text"] = "Salvar"
        self.autenticar["font"] = ("Calibri", "8")
        self.autenticar["width"] = 12
        self.autenticar["command"]
        self.autenticar.pack()


        self.mensagem = Label(self.quartoContainer, text="", font=self.fontePadrao)
        self.mensagem.pack()

        #salvar em uma lista, nome e telefone, e aplicar uma função no button salvar para ele salvar e sair

        f = open('ListaTelefonica.txt', 'a')
        f.write('Nome:  - Telefone: ')
        f.close


        print('\nLista Telefonica\n')




root = Tk()
root.title('List Save')
Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, tudo bem?

Você pode fazer assim:

```
from tkinter import *

class Application:
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.fontePadrao = ("Arial", "10")
        self.primeiroContainer = Frame(master)
        self.primeiroContainer["pady"] = 10
        self.primeiroContainer.pack()

        self.segundoContainer = Frame(master)
        self.segundoContainer["padx"] = 20
        self.segundoContainer.pack()

        self.terceiroContainer = Frame(master)
        self.terceiroContainer["padx"] = 20
        self.terceiroContainer.pack()

        self.quartoContainer = Frame(master)
        self.quartoContainer["pady"] = 20
        self.quartoContainer.pack()

        self.titulo = Label(self.primeiroContainer, text="Lista Telefonica")
        self.titulo["font"] = ("Arial", "10", "bold")
        self.titulo.pack()

        self.nomeLabel = Label(self.segundoContainer,text="Nome", font=self.fontePadrao)
        self.nomeLabel.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.nome = Entry(self.segundoContainer)
        self.nome["width"] = 30
        self.nome["font"] = self.fontePadrao
        self.nome.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.telefoneLabel = Label(self.terceiroContainer, text="Telefone:", font=self.fontePadrao)
        self.telefoneLabel.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.senha = Entry(self.terceiroContainer)
        self.senha["width"] = 30
        self.senha["font"] = self.fontePadrao
        self.senha["show"] = ""
        self.senha.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.autenticar = Button(self.quartoContainer, command=self.enviar)
        self.autenticar["text"] = "Salvar"
        self.autenticar["font"] = ("Calibri", "8")
        self.autenticar["width"] = 12
        self.autenticar["command"]
        self.autenticar.pack()


        self.mensagem = Label(self.quartoContainer, text="", font=self.fontePadrao)
        self.mensagem.pack()

    def enviar(self):        
        with open('ListaTelefonica.txt', 'a') as _file:
            _file.write(f'Nome: {self.nome.get()} - Telefone: {self.senha.get()}\n')

        # Limpa o que está escrito no nome e telefone
        self.nome.delete(0, END)
        self.senha.delete(0, END)        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('\nLista Telefonica\n')

    root = Tk()
    root.title('List Save')
    Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ajudou bastante, agradeço!

Comment: se ajudou, favor marcar como respondida.